# symfony 3.4 under ubuntu

Tags: symfony, installation

Hello I have installed Symfony 3.4 under ubuntu using composer - however instead of the usual symfony welcome I get the following:
[image]

I am running PHP 7 as can be seen here:
[image]

Anyone know how I can get this symfony running properly??

Comment: Did you also install the apache htaccess file? https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#adding-rewrite-rules

Comment: Have you configured a vhost ?

Comment: I have a .htaccess - but the recommended one seems to point to web/ which is not there?

Comment: You used flex to install your app which results in a different directory system.  The web directory is now called public.  You need to follow the directions in the link I gave to get the proper htaccess file.  And probably need a vhost as well.  Why not follow the examples in the docs until you see how the pieces fit together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move into your project directory and run this command:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public
```

Comment: changing .htaccess to point to public and running the above php command has fixed the problem